# How to show image in view panorama image in Swift (objective c)?

Tags: 360-panorama

How can I view like this in Swift or objective c? I need images like the ones shown here:

https://msnautosblob.akamaized.net/izmo-prod/izmo360/en-us/2017/lexus/rx/pano/izmoPano.html

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: i want show spot point (i have show panorama image like example link) and hope interaction it!!

Comment: i find some third part for it, https://www.webrotate360.com/ for out and https://ggnome.com/pano2vr for in and more ....